# zsh autocomplete results from function

Tags: zsh, tmux, autocomplete, tab-completion

I've been searching and searching and unable to find a clear way to do this:

*Slightly contrived example to hide details*: Say I want to autocomplete tmux session names with a command that will open them.

So say `tmux-open $NAME` opens said tmux session, and `tmux-ls` lists all of the possible session names separated by newlines.

How can I configure zsh so that `tmux-open <TAB>` autocompletes with the list of possible sessions from `tmux-ls`.

Answer (score 4):

Figured it out. It was pretty simple and so a lot of the guides seemed to skip over something like this and go onto more complex stuff. In `~/.zshrc`:

```
function _tmux_completions() {
  local -a sessions
  sessions=($(tmux-ls))
  compadd -a sessions
}
compdef _tmux_completions tmux-open
```